# Read text file with repeated pattern into list

Tags: java, file, format, delimiter, file-handling

I'm trying to create a Tile Map Editor for Java and I'm stuck on the file opening. Opening up the file itself isn't a great deal but it creats runtime Errors as soon as i put in whitespaces in the textfile. Each tile consists of an Image (black or whit square atm) and whether it is going to be solid (1) or not (0). The tilemaps will currently be saved in a Format like this:

```
1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1
1:1 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 1:1
1:1 0:0 0:0 0:0 0:0 1:1
1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1 1:1
```

This for example could be a simple room with black walls that are solid and will block the Player. It would be a 6x4 tile map. How can I define the Format x:x(whitespace here)?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
File file = new File("file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = null;
try 
{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to store in each element of your List?  A single 1:1 or the whole line of them?  The exception is happening when you trying to parseInt on a line full of colons. Why are you trying to parseInt on this line containing colons?  If you're wanting to parse out your int's, then what do you want each element in the list to look like?

Comment: Well the Code example above is for attempts to make it work on a much more fundamential level. In the real case i have a List<Tile> TileMap. Tile is a class consisting of int ID and int Type with their getters() and setters(). So i'd like to store the first 1 as the ID and the second 1 as type and going on like that for each Tile element in the list.
Edit: what i'm looking for is like the c# scanf Arguments %d or %r etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While guessing that this is what you're asking for, something like this then...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadTextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Tile> list = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        String path = "C:/whatever/your/path/is/";
        File file = new File(path + "file.txt");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] pairs = text.split(" ");
                for(String pair : pairs) {
                    String[] chars = pair.split(":");
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(chars[0]);
                    int type = Integer.parseInt(chars[1]);
                    list.add(new Tile(id, type));
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}

class Tile {
    int id;
    int type;

    Tile(int id, int type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tile [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: Perfect! Could nearly implement it one to one. I'll spend my time revising the streams and their possibilities :) The only thing to Change will be that the program recognizes the end of a line in the txt file. I think i can do that with a hexadecimal Editor which will Show me what kind of character is used for newline and then check it in my program. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: Shouldn't i close the BufferedReader?

Comment: The BufferedReader is automatically closed.  Notice how it is instantiated using the try-with-resources implementation (available since JDK7).  Also, notice that BufferedReader implements AutoCloseable; anything that implements AutoCloseable can be used inside a try-with-resources statement.  Yes, doing this using Streams would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just bothered by the whitespaces, change the code to

```
 while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(text.trim()));
}
```

But i assume this will not work because you cannot convert the entire line as Integer so i would recommend:

```
 while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String[] values = text.split(":")
    for(String val : values)
    {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(val.trim()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you definitely brought me on the right track. Like i just said in the comment above, i will only have to find out how the bufferedreader knows when the line in the txt-file is finished.